# FreeBSD Partition Size

Tags: storage, freebsd

I have the following df -h output:

```
/dev/mfid0s1d    9.7G    8.9G     28K   100%    /var
```

However, when I try to du -hs /var, I got this result:

```
#du -hs /var
3.3G    /var
```

My question is, where is my 5.6G data?
Or, maybe there's something I don't understand about freebsd?

My server info:

```
#uname -a
FreeBSD blablbalba.example.com 8.0-STABLE FreeBSD 8.0-STABLE #0: Sat Apr 10 04:13:38 WIT 2010     adminmail@blablabla.example.com:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

Comment: What kind of storage volume is `mfid0s1d`? Some unices (e.g. Solaris) can have multiple filesystems sharing the same storage area, so this situation could arise if `/var` and another filesystem shared a 9.6GB volume. I don't know if this exists in FreeBSD.

Comment: @Giles: I'm not really sure how to check it. Do know the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sysadmin told be that `du` & `dh` something give a delayed result. Because, after several minutes, I check back and `du` did display right value.